# How to select columns in an R dataframe based on string matching

Tags: r, dplyr

I don't think this *exact* question has been asked yet (for R, anyway).

I want to retain any columns in my dataset (there are hundreds in actuality) that contain a certain string, and drop the rest. I have found plenty of examples of string searching column *names*, but nothing for the contents of the columns themselves.

As an example, say I have this dataset:

```
df = data.frame(v1 = c(1, 8, 7, 'No number'),
                v2 = c(5, 3, 5, 1),
                v3 = c('Nothing', 4, 2, 9),
                v4 = c(3, 8, 'Something', 6))
```

For this example, say I want to retain any columns with the string `No`, so that the resulting dataset is:

```
         v1      v3
1         1 Nothing
2         8       4
3         7       2
4 No number       9
```

How can I do this in R? I am happy with any sort of solution (e.g., base R, `dplyr`, etc.)!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base R :

```
df[colSums(sapply(df, grepl, pattern = 'No')) > 0]

#         v1      v3
#1         1 Nothing
#2         8       4
#3         7       2
#4 No number       9
```

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select(where(~any(grepl('No', .))))
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply

```
df[grep("No", df)]
#          v1      v3
# 1         1 Nothing
# 2         8       4
# 3         7       2
# 4 No number       9
```

This works, because `grep` internally checks if `if (!is.character(x))` and if that's true it basically does:

```
s <- structure(as.character(df), names = names(df))
s
# v1 
# "c(\"1\", \"8\", \"7\", \"No number\")" 
# v2 
# "c(5, 3, 5, 1)" 
# v3 
# "c(\"Nothing\", \"4\", \"2\", \"9\")" 
# v4 
# "c(\"3\", \"8\", \"Something\", \"6\")" 
grep("No", s)
# [1] 1 3
```

*Note:*

```
R.version.string
# [1] "R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)"
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. What version of R are you on?

Comment: R4.0.2 works for me too. But never seen this. `data.frame` doesn't seem to be mentioned in the `grep()` documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Use `dplyr::select_if()` function:

```
df <- df %>% select_if(function(col) any(grepl("No", col)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run `grepl` for each column and if there's any value in there, pick it.

```
df = data.frame(v1 = c(1, 8, 7, 'No number'),
                v2 = c(5, 3, 5, 1),
                v3 = c('Nothing', 4, 2, 9),
                v4 = c(3, 8, 'Something', 6))

find.no <- sapply(X = df, FUN = function(x) {
  any(grep("No", x = x))
})

> df[, find.no]
         v1      v3
1         1 Nothing
2         8       4
3         7       2
4 No number       9
```