# Filtering an exact character match in multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I am using dplyr to filter columns that contain "Yes"

```r
df %>%
  filter(col1 == "Yes")
```

How can I do this across multiple columns?

Answer (score 5):

We may use `if_any` (to subset rows where any of the columns have the "Yes") or `if_all` (only subset rows where all the columns in the selected columns have 'Yes' in that row)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   filter(if_any(everything(), ~ .x == "Yes"))
```

`everything()` selects all the columns.  If we need to apply only on a subset of columns, use either a character vector of column names or index i.e.

```
df1 %>%
    filter(if_all(c(col1, col2), ~ .x == "Yes"))
```

Comment: this answer was helpful for me. Thank you. Have you answered any questions, where instead of `filter` we can select columns values where the vector matches? Tried, `select` but it did not work. This is not like, I'm not subsetting the column_names based on the vector of names.

Comment: @user5249203 You can just use `df1[yourvec]` if all the columns are in the yourvec, or if there are some not present, `df1[intersect(names(df1), yourvec)]`

Comment: I am not trying to subset the column names. I am trying to subset any column in the DF, where the value in that column matches the value in the vector.

Comment: @user5249203 With the `if_any` or `if_all`, you can change the code to `~ .x %in% yourvec` it probably need any or all wrapping.  Without a small reproducible example, it is not clear

Comment: I found a question in similar lines, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65437051/how-to-select-columns-in-an-r-dataframe-based-on-string-matching. they are doing partial match I need an exact match. Was just wondering if you have answered similar one as I like the asnwers you provide

Comment: @user5249203 try `df %>% select(where(~ any(.x %in% yourvec)))` if it is just to have at least one element from your vector.  If you want to select only columns that have all the elements in the vector, use `df %>% select(where(~ all(yourvec %in% .x )))` or may be reverse order

Comment: Had to use `df %>% dplyr::select(c(1:5,where(~ any(.x %in% vect))))`, to retain specific columns I needed alog with the selected data. Thank you

Comment: @user5249203 glad it worked for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244030/discussion-between-user5249203-and-akrun).

Comment: @user5249203 i was in the chatroom, but didn't find you there